# How to launch an external process synchronously in Electron

Tags: electron

In Electron,

I need to call an external program to do some work, wait for it to finish and terminate, and then move on to my next line of code.

I've tried `shell.openItem("/applications/apptocall.app")`

This works to launch the app, but it runs the next line of code in my electron app immediately instead of waiting for the externally launched app to finish.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `shell.openItem` command of the Electron API is not meant to control the execution of external executables.

Instead, check out the node.js API for `child_process.execFileSync` ([Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options)).

There are certain limitations when using the child_process API along with ASAR archive packaging in Electron concerning fs.stats and child_process.spawn, you should read up on these issues [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#extra-unpacking-on-some-apis).